# getting 401 Unauthorized error retrofit in android?

Tags: android, retrofit, unauthorized

I am facing problem when I am trying to login using retrofit.

Its shows 401 unauthorized. I have tried lots of times!

Can not find the exact solution! In postman/Advanced Rest Client its working fine.
What should I do to login, please anyone help!

[In okhttp its shows the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9TYU.png)

[postman also respose perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xDUL.png)

[Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iED2V.png)

Comment: Please provide your code and also screenshot from postman request and response

Comment: I have Attached please click the Image title link (In okhttp its shows the data)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the body is {"password","phone"}, but in postman it is {"employee_phone","employee_password"}, try to use the same names in postman

Comment: Please @Hagar check this link i have attached all the important code!
https://pastebin.com/7DNy0HH7

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is my output now showing!
I am getting the response body null but in okhttp body getting the data perfectly! 
how can i get the data from response body!

[Here is the image link please check!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJEeg.png)

[Okhttp image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6W8H.png)